# Firefox Developer Edition console message

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

On an almost blank page served through local server, console logs these messages :

> runtime.onMessage: tabupdate
>   runtime.onMessage: update_shortcuts

Tried reading documentation but don't understand why this is firing up.

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Localhost</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to debug code that do not include the code do not get answers. We can't see your screen from where we're sitting.

Comment: Apologies, added the code being used.
Additional informaton: I don't get those logs in chrome or regular Firefox.
Working on El Capitan OS should it add any extra info.